# Redis read all key for a given cacheName

Tags: java, redis, spring-data

Is it possible to read all keys for a given *cacheName* from *Redis*.

Let me explain what I am looking for.

I am saving `Student` data and `Teacher` data to `Redis` cache, using the following code.

```
    // Saving Student data to cache
    @Override
    @CachePut(cacheNames = "student", key = "#student.studentId", unless = "#result==null")
    public Student cacheData(final Student student) {
        return student;
    }

    // Saving Teacher data to cache
    @Override
    @CachePut(cacheNames = "teacher", key = "#teacher.teacherId", unless = "#result==null")
    public Teacher cacheData(final Teacher teacher) {
        return teacher;
    }
```

Now I need to get all keys of Student from cache (i.e `studentId`). I have tried the following code to list the keys, but it is not returning the ids/keys as expected.

```
for (String key : redisTemplate.keys("*")) { //printing all keys from cache
  System.out.println(key);
}

for (String key : redisTemplate.keys("student*")) { //it is just printing student~keys as string.
  System.out.println(key);
}
```

Can anyone help me to print all `student` keys from redis cache?

Comment: I guess by using `redisTemplate.keys("student*")` you're getting list of all keys starting with `student`, then what else you needed? 
Can you please specify with some example of stored keys and your required result?

Comment: It is printing `student~keys` as string.. instead it should print all keys of student.

Comment: Lets say that I have 2 `student` and 2 `teacher` objects saved in cache with ids `s1`, `s2`, `t1`, `t2` respectively. from that need to fetch `s1` and `s2`